# How to make slider auto loop?

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I use this [Jquery slider](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/rtl.html)

How can I do auto loop, that it will go around in mobile version?

I tried this code:

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    rtl:true,
    loop:true,
    nav:true,

})
```

Comment: I think you need to add the option: `autoplay` - https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html#autoplay

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one more parameter in owl-carousel config:

autoplay: true,

please refer the owl document for other options: 
https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html

Comment: I did this, it works, but I need to continue to slide in right direction when I reach the end

Comment: I mean when  I dragging the latest slide, it does not goto to first

Comment: which version of carousel you are using ?
You can update the slider to the v2 (or beta 2.4), to make it scroll infinitely. It has a new parameter (loop: true), which does this. 
 check this demo (May be useful): https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/autoplay.html

Comment: So when you are dragging the last one, what is the expected result?

Comment: I expect that slide will be started again from by right direction.